# Mongodb aggregate by date with empty daybins

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to do a per-day aggregation in MongoDB. I already have an aggregation where I successfully group the data by day. However, I want to do the aggregation in such a way where **days with no data show up, but empty**. That is, they are empty bins.

Below is what I have so far. I have not been able to find anything in the MongoDB documentation or otherwise that suggests how to do aggregations and produce empty bins:

```
app.models.profile_view.aggregate(
    { $match: { user: req.user._id , 'viewing._type': 'user' } },
    { $project: { 
        day: {'$dayOfMonth': '$start'},month: {'$month':'$start'},year: {'$year':'$start'},
        duration: '$duration'
    } },
    { $group: {
        _id: { day:'$day', month:'$month', year:'$year' },
        count: { $sum: 1 },
        avg_duration: { $avg: '$duration' }
    } },
    { $project: { _id: 0, date: '$_id', count: 1, avg_duration: 1 }}
).exec().then(function(time_series) {
    console.log(time_series)
    return res.send(200, [{ key: 'user', values: time_series }])
}, function(err) {
    console.log(err.stack)
    return res.send(500, { error: err, code: 200, message: 'Failed to retrieve profile view data' })
})
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to solve this problem using aggregation. When you use $group, mongo can only group based on the data you are providing it. In this case, how would mongo know which date values are missing or even what the range of acceptable dates is?

I think your best option would be to add the missing date values to the result of your aggregation.

Comment: Agreed. A good way to think about it is to realize that, when you want to create a document from a `$group` stage that is an empty bucket, you are asking MongoDB to create a result document from an input set of 0 documents. The simplest thing to do is probably to add the empty buckets in your application code based on your extra knowledge about expected date ranges.

Comment: Agreed as well. I didn't think it was possible.

Comment: But now I realise that I shouldn't do it anyway. If I'm showing a graph of profile views, I would get a lot of sharp peaks if there are days where nobody viewed a profile. The graph would look much smoother without the empty day bins.

Answer (score 2):

Starting in `Mongo 5.1`, it's a perfect use case for the new [`$densify`](https://docs.mongodb.com/upcoming/reference/operator/aggregation/densify/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-densify) aggregation operator:

```
// { date: ISODate("2021-12-05") }
// { date: ISODate("2021-12-05") }
// { date: ISODate("2021-12-03") }
// { date: ISODate("2021-12-07") }
db.collection.aggregate([

  { $group: {
    _id: { $dateTrunc: { date: "$date", unit: "day" } },
    total: { $count: {} }
  }},
  // { _id: ISODate("2021-12-03"), total: 1 }
  // { _id: ISODate("2021-12-05"), total: 2 }
  // { _id: ISODate("2021-12-07"), total: 1 }

  { $densify: { field: "_id", range: { step: 1, unit: "day", bounds: "full" } } },
  // { _id: ISODate("2021-12-03"), total: 1 }
  // { _id: ISODate("2021-12-04") }
  // { _id: ISODate("2021-12-05"), total: 2 }
  // { _id: ISODate("2021-12-06") }
  // { _id: ISODate("2021-12-07"), total: 1 }

  { $project: {
    day: "$_id",
    _id: 0,
    total: { $cond: [ { $not: ["$total"] }, 0, "$total" ] }
  }}
])
// { day: ISODate("2021-12-03"), total: 1 }
// { day: ISODate("2021-12-04"), total: 0 }
// { day: ISODate("2021-12-05"), total: 2 }
// { day: ISODate("2021-12-06"), total: 0 }
// { day: ISODate("2021-12-07"), total: 1 }
```

This:

- `$group`s documents by day with their `$count`

  - [`$dateTrunc`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateTrunc/) truncates your `date`s at the beginning of their `day` (the truncation `unit`).
- `$densif`ies documents ([`$densify`](https://docs.mongodb.com/upcoming/reference/operator/aggregation/densify/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-densify)) by creating new documents in a sequence of documents where certain values for a `field` (in our case `field: "_id"`) are missing:

  - the step for our densification is 1 day: `range: { step: 1, unit: "day" }`
- finally transforms (`$project`) fields:

  - renames `_id` to `day`
  - add the `total` field for new documents included during the densify stage (`{ views: { $cond: [ { $not: ["$views"] }, 0, "$views" ] }`)